# How can I sync Calendars and Contacts to my iPod (3rd Gen)?

Tags: itunes, macos, calendar, contacts, ipod

I have a 3rd generation iPod (Apple calls it an "iPod (Dock Connector)").  It syncs music, podcasts and audiobooks with iTunes 12.5.3 on El Capitan, but calendars and contacts are not synced.  (I didn't notice this previously, because until recently I didn't use Apples calendar/contact apps).  iPod has most recent firmware (Settings > About reports version 2.3).

How can I get calendar events and contacts to sync with this vintage iPod?

Comment: What iOS version is on your iPod?

Comment: My iPod predates the first release of the operating system that would later be named iOS by four years.